# why opencms use java code to sort content docs, other than use sql, like "date desc, name asc"?

Tags: java, opencms

I wonder if there are some other techniques to use here lazily? It seems to be so hard to define a new Comparator.
Here is the code of CmsDateResourceComparator compare method:

```
    public int compare(CmsResource res0, CmsResource res1) {

    if (res0 == res1) {
        return 0;
    }

    CmsDateResourceComparator key0 = m_keys.get(res0.getStructureId());
    CmsDateResourceComparator key1 = m_keys.get(res1.getStructureId());

    if (key0 == null) {
        // initialize key if null
        key0 = CmsDateResourceComparator.create(m_cms, res0, m_dateIdentifiers);
        m_keys.put(res0.getStructureId(), key0);
    }
    if (key1 == null) {
        // initialize key if null
        key1 = CmsDateResourceComparator.create(m_cms, res1, m_dateIdentifiers);
        m_keys.put(res1.getStructureId(), key1);
    }

    if (m_asc) {
        // sort in ascending order
        if (key0.m_date > key1.m_date) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (key0.m_date < key1.m_date) {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        // sort in descending order
        if (key0.m_date > key1.m_date) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (key0.m_date < key1.m_date) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCms 8 you can use the Solr **byQuery** Collector. With this collector you can perform solr queries. This is a powerful function...

```
<cms:contentload collector="byQuery" 2 param="type:v8flower"> 
    <cms:contentaccess var="content" /> 
    ${content.value.Title} 
</cms:contentload>
```